# CSS Align Icon and Text in an LI - Vertical-Align to working

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<li id="myLI">
<a id="myAnchor" href="#">
<img src="/icons/icon.png">Click Here</a>
</li>
```

I need to get the text to align in the middle of the icon (vertically), so I tried adding: vertical-align:middle but it's not working.

Can anyone advice please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#myLI a#myAnchor img{
float:left;
margin:margin to center;
}
```

Margin to center is the values that you need to give according to the center of the text. eg margin : 5px 5px 0px 2px;

Comment: the best way to do this is to have the image(icon) as a background. this is because google will ignore the background. You dont want google to index all your icons. I always do this insted. #myLI a#myAnchor{background:url(icon.png) no-repeat 0px 5px; padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;} where 0px in background is left margin, 5px is top margin . and in padding you need to give space to the left of the text to accommodate the image.... this will be better for all the browsers as well....